# How to automate desktop/web applications on citrix

Tags: testing, automation, citrix

I have bunch of different applications that are on Citrix. Is UiPath my only options? ..I find the tool so boring. Is there any other options?.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other options are Blue Prism or Automation Anywhere, but they will probably be just as boring.

The problem with automating Citrix is that all you are getting is an image of the user interface. No elements of the application are able to be viewed or interacted with. Therefore, the only option is using OCR to scan for text or other objects and return the relative screen position (x, y) coordinates. Then, you use those coordinates to input text or click checkboxes or whatever.

If you are looking to write code, you can probably get the screen position using an OCR class library or API. There's one available here [ocr.space/ocrapi](https://ocr.space/OCRAPI). It supports several languages, and might be useful if you want to go that route.